# How can replace inheritance with interfaces in factory pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am dynamically adding and replacing controls in a winform panel at runtime

Even though all works I have been told to implement interfaces rather than inheriting from a baseUserControl.

I am all for it but I dont see how I can I achieve the same result using interfaces

How would I code my Factory?

How can this be improved and use interfaces instead ?

```
//Simplified noddy example

//Client code
var controlA = ControlFactory
    .Create("UserControlA") as UserControlA;

panel1.Controls.Add(ControlA);

//Factory
public class ControlFactory
{
    public static BaseUserControl Create(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "UserControlA":
                var userControlA = new UserControlA();

                return userControlA;

            case "UserControlB":
                var userControlB = new UserControlB();
                return userControlB;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
   //BaseUserControl
   public partial class BaseUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public BaseUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public virtual void DoSomething()
        {

        }
    }

    public partial class UserControlA : BaseUserControl
    {
        public UserControlA()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override void DoSomething()
        {
            //Do something here
        }
    }

public partial class UserControlB : BaseUserControl
{
    public UserControlB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why? What would the advantage of using interfaces over the base class be?

Comment: These are not exclusive.  Your IUserControl can declare DoSomething(), and you can implement BaseControl as implementing IUserControl (and return a IUserControl from the factory).

Comment: Maybe your BaseUserControl should implement the Interface.  Then all classes deriving from it would be the type expected by the using classes.

Comment: @Oded Totally agree.Have you ever worked in a place where your manager comes along and "glances" at your code and says "dont like inheritance use interfaces" . Since the factory returns a usercontrol ,not sure it can be done.

Comment: @SteveWellens  Can do that but then how will this change the signature of my "Create " method in my factory?

Comment: Sounds like it might actually be the manager who needs to be reprogrammed.

Comment: @SeanU - I tried that once but the individual had read-only memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here’s how you can do it:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

//Interface
public interface IControl : IComponent
{
    void DoSomething();
}

//Factory
public class ControlFactory
{
    public static IControl Create(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "UserControlA":
                var userControlA = new UserControlA();

                return userControlA;

            case "UserControlB":
                var userControlB = new UserControlB();
                return userControlB;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

//BaseUserControl
public partial class BaseUserControl : UserControl, IControl
{
    public BaseUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}

public partial class UserControlA : BaseUserControl, IControl
{
    public UserControlA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do something here
    }
}

public partial class UserControlB : BaseUserControl, IControl
{
    public UserControlB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

You can retain `BaseUserControl` if you have any functionality that is common to `UserControlA` and `UserControlB`; otherwise, eliminate it and make the latter two derive directly from `UserControl`.

You *should* define all members you might need to access from your derived classes within your `IControl` interface. This includes any members you will inherit from `UserControl`. However, you will not need to re-implement these within your concrete classes.

```
//Interface
public interface IControl : IComponent
{
    void DoSomething();

    // To be inherited from UserControl.
    Size Size { get; set; }
    bool Focus();
    event EventHandler FontChanged;
}
```

If you need to add these controls to a Windows Forms application – typically as the argument to a [`Control.ControlCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add.aspx) method call – you will need to get a `Control` instance corresponding to your control. Under the current implementation, this may be achieved simply through casting; however, this needs to be insulated from the consumers of your interface, in case you decide to change the underlying implementation in the future. Thus, I would use:

```
//Interface
public interface IControl : IComponent
{
    void DoSomething();

    Control AsWindowsForms();
}

//BaseUserControl
public partial class BaseUserControl : UserControl, IControl
{
    public BaseUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {

    }

    public Control AsWindowsForms()
    {
        return this as Control;
    }
}
```

In your client code:

```
var controlA = ControlFactory.Create("UserControlA").AsWindowsForms();
var controlB = ControlFactory.Create("UserControlB").AsWindowsForms();
panel1.Controls.Add(controlA);
panel1.Controls.Add(controlB);
```